# Prerequisites for geometric analysis.

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

I have knowledge in differential geometry of curves and surfaces and in partial differential equations (just methods of solving PDEs). And I know algebraic topology up to fundamental group theory. So I just want to know what are the prerequisites to learn geometric analysis.

Comment: Sounds like the first step is to learn a fair amount of real analysis (up to Sobolev spaces) and graduate differential geometry. I'm assuming you have a solid foundation in multivariable analysis.

Comment: [this](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642212987) will give you a good start.

Comment: I would say, just keep going in both PDE and differential/Riemannian geometry, and eventually you'll see more and more how they fit together.